Proving differentiability at a point - Confusion?
(For a more fleshed-out example demonstrating my confusion, see this post. In John's answer, why do we have the "smoothness" condition? Wouldn't this be necessary if and only when dealing with continuous differentiability? This is different from differentiability.)
Let's say we have been given a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ which is differentiable everywhere except possibly $x=-1.$ How would we determine whether $f$ is differentiable at $x=-1$?
This seems like an extremely simple, elementary question from beginner-level calculus, but the solutions I have found aren't making much sense. In the linked question (see link here...again), it seems that answers assume differentiability at $x=-1$ is necessary and sufficient to showing that $$\lim_{x\to -1^{-}} \frac{df}{dx}=\lim_{x\to-1^{+}}\frac{df}{dx}.$$
My understanding, though, is that this would be the necessary and sufficient property for checking if the function is continuously differentiable, not just differentiable. Is this wrong? And why, if so? I would expect that in order to show $f$ is differentiable at point $x=-1,$ it is necessary and sufficient to show that $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h-1)-f(-1)}{h}$$ exists.
I appreciate any help I can get. (I'm prepping for GRE Math Subject Test.) Thank you!

Can you explain what do you mean by "continuously differentiable"? Do  you mean that the derivative is continuous?

@SineoftheTime Yes, exactly that.

I'm not sure I understand the question, but there are functions continuous everywhere, differentiable everywhere but the derivative is not continuous

@SineoftheTime Looking at the linked question: When trying to find the values for $a,b,c>0$ so that the function will be differentiable, why is it that the responses to the question use the fact that lim${x\to-1^{-}}\frac{df}{dx}=$lim${x\to-1^{+}}=\frac{df}{dx}?$ My understanding is that such equality will hold true if and only when discussing continuous differentiability.

check the limit you listed for h approaching zero from both direction. If the limits exist and the same, then it's differentiable at x=-1.

@goldboy But would it be a necessary condition? That is, if differentiable, then limits are equal from both directions?

Continuously differentiable has a specific meaning which is not the same as continuous and differentiable.  For a function to be differentiable, it must be continuous.  So, you can go back to the formal definition $f'(x) = \lim_\limits {h\to 0} \frac {f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$ and if $f(x)$ is not continuous at $f(-1)$ neither will $f'(x)$ or with piecewise functions $\lim_\limits {x\to -1^-} f(x) =  \lim_\limits {x\to -1^+} f(x)$ and $\lim_\limits {x\to -1^-} f'(x) =  \lim_\limits {x\to -1^+} f'(x)$

(i) Your final understanding (the Newton quotient definition) is correct. (ii) Assuming $f$ is continuous, the "one-sided limits of the derivative exist and are equal" condition is sufficient (implies $f'(-1)$ exists and is equal to the common limit) but not necessary (there are differentiable functions such that one or both one-sided limits of the derivative fail to exist). (iii) If it matters, there do not exist differentiable functions for which the one-sided limits of the derivative exist and are unequal. <> All these are addressed elsewhere on site, hence the comment instead of an answer.

@AndrewD.Hwang I see. So, I guess my question now is then when will it be necessary that both the left- and right-limits are equal at every point? Will it be whenever both left- and right-limits exist? If so, then that would answer my initial question.

Your "initial question" has been fully anwered by @Andrew, who just omitted some link helping to close this post as a duplicate. If you have a new question, better edit a (clear and) new post.

@AnneBauval Thank you for providing me with a post on here which answers my question.

@AnneBauval Hello again. Just re-read you comment here, my initial question hadn’t been fully answered by Andrew’s comment. He provided some fine input, though the answer to my initial question had yet to be provided. My initial question was almost entirely about the necessity of left- and right-limits being equal. Please don’t be leaving such rude remarks in the future. It’s not very welcoming to others on the site. (I appreciate the duplicate answer link again.)

Coda: The basic go-to fact for my point (iii) is often called Darboux's theorem. Loosely, "derivatives do not have jump discontinuities." In more detail, if $f$ is differentiable on some set containing $[a, b]$, and if $z$ is a real number strictly between $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$, then there exists a $c$ in $(a, b)$ such that $f'(c) = z$. N.b. this does not assume $f'$ is continuous. (!!) Consequently, if $f$ is continuous, differentiable except possibly at some $x_0$, and if the one-sided limits of $f'$ exist at $x_0$, then $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ iff the one-sided limits are equal.
